# Getting one point with coordinates for polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, coordinates, degrees-minutes-seconds

I drew a polygon and after that, I extracted the vertices to eventually get the coordinates of the area.

As shown in the screen capture I've got my y/latitude and x/longitude but I would like to get one line with a format that looks like

[image]

How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks in your posts.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this expression. It works for points, polygons and lines and independent of the sourcelayers CRS:

```
to_dms(y(centroid(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326'))),'y',4,'suffix')
 || ' and ' ||
to_dms(x(centroid(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326'))),'x',4,'suffix')
```

If you want to add it as field to your attribute table, make sure the new field is of type string.

---

To break this into pieces and explain it a little:

- `transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')` transforms the geometry from whatever source CRS to WGS84 (lat/lon)
- `centroid(*transformed_geometry*)` extracts the centroid from this geometry. You can also use other expressions like `point_on_surface()` here or leave it out when working with singlepoint-layers.
- `y(*geometry*)` and `x(*geometry*)` extract the y/lat and x/lon coordinate of the geometry.
- `to_dms(*coordinate*,*axis*,*precision*,*formatting*)` finally converts lat/lon coordinates to degree, minutes, seconds. The `coordinate` must be a latitude or longitude value as double/real. `axis` is a string, expecting `'x'` or `'y'` depending on your `coordinate`. `precision` is the argument defining the number of decimals for the output. And `formatting` finally is an optional argument. You can use `NULL`, `'aligned'` or `'suffix'` here. `NULL` will lead to e.g. `6°9′16.445″`, `'aligned'` to e.g.
  `6°09′16.4452″N` and `'suffix'` to e.g. `6°9′16.4452″N`. [See the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-dms).

Comment: @Robagb, keep also in mind, that besides the `centroid()` function, there are also `point_on_surface()` and `pole_of_inaccessibility()`, see [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometry-functions) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

**The idea**

Use the following expression to automatically get a list of the coordinates of the vertices of each polygon you add.

**Get WKT (well known text)**

The basis of this solution is to convert the geometry to it's WKT (text) representation with this expression:

```
geom_to_wkt($geometry)
```

**Format coordinates**

To remove unwanted brackets, spaces and the string `polygon`, use this slightly modified expression:

```
regexp_replace(geom_to_wkt($geometry), '(Polygon)( )(\\(\\()','')
```

Now, you can automatically format these coordinates the way you want by expanding the expression accordingly. To get a list formatted the way you want and with the coordinates of each vertex on an own line, use this expression:

```
array_to_string(
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (0, num_points( $geometry),1),
        with_variable (
            'all',
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (0, num_points( $geometry),1),
                with_variable(
                    'coord',
                    string_to_array(
                        regexp_replace(
                            geom_to_wkt($geometry), 
                            '(Polygon)( )(\\(*)',''
                        )
                    ),
                    string_to_array(
                        to_string (@coord[@element]))[0] || '\n' 
                )
            ),
            to_dms ( 
                 substr( 
                    right (@all[@element], 19),
                    regexp_match (right (@all[@element], 19),' ')+1,11
                )
                ,
                'y', 
                4, 
                'suffix'
            ) || 
            ' and '  || 
            to_dms (left (@all[@element], 11), 'x', 4, 'suffix') ||  
            '\n' 
        )
    )
)
```

*The polygon is labeled with the expression above: a list of the coordinates of all vertices in the desired format is automatically generated - check the separately generated vertices layer (blue dots) for visual control:*

[image]