# Replace all but coordinates from a WKT string, including closing bracket ')'

Tags: qgis, expression, string, regular-expression

To get a list of coordinates from a polygon and remove unwanted parts from the resulting string, the following expression works fine to remove the string elements `'Polygon'`, spaces   and opening brackets `(`:

```
regexp_replace(
    geom_to_wkt($geometry), 
    '(Polygon)( )(\\(*)',
    ''
)
```

However, I struggle to find a way to similarily remove closing brackets `)`. To remove **only** these brackets, this regex works fine: `'(\\))'`. But when I add this as another capturing group in line 3 of the expression like `'(Polygon)( )(\\(*)(\\))'`, nothing is replaced at all.

How can I remove all unnecessary characters, including closing brackets? For context, [see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/426817/88814).

Comment: So, if I suggest you this `array_foreach(string_to_array(replace(replace(geom_to_wkt($geometry), 'Polygon ((', ''), ')', ''), ', '),  string_to_array(@element, ' '))` it probably won't help you much ?

Comment: Indeed, this is not what I was looking for. Like this, I could have used a simple `replace` function: `replace (regexp_replace( geom_to_wkt($geometry), '(Polygon)( )(\\(*)', '' ),')','')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other solution:

```
regexp_replace(
     geom_to_wkt($geometry),
    '(Polygon \\(\\()(.+)(\\)\\))',
    '\\2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all alphabetic characters and (round) parentheses:

```
regexp_replace(
    geom_to_wkt($geometry), 
    '[A-Za-z()]',
    ''
)
```

As pointed out by @pigreco, the leading space can be removed by wrapping `regexp_replace` in the `trim` function.

```
trim(
    regexp_replace(
        geom_to_wkt($geometry), 
        '[A-Za-z()]',
        ''
    )
)
```

Comment: a space is required, otherwise the output string would contain a leading space

Comment: I saw that you added the space in `[ A-Za-z()]`, but this removes the space between the coordinates too !!!

Comment: I suggest to use the `trim` function like this, so you remove the white space at the beginning `trim(regexp_replace(geom_to_wkt($geometry),[A-Za-z()]',''))`

Comment: Apologies, I was away from the computer and quickly made the edit on my phone. Lesson learned and thanks for correction.

Comment: Changed accepted answer to @pigreco's one for his efforts both in his answer as well as here, even though both answers would have deserved it. Matt's solution together with the trim function is probably what I would use.